# Error while opening themes page in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

I Just installed Wordpress 5.2.3. And I installed EIKRA theme. After activating theme I am unable to open appearance->themes. It is giving me the error that, "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions". There is no problem on any other page. other dashboard features are working even the theme is also activated. There is no error in plugins as well because I have not installed any yet. I am working on localhost.

I have enabled the debugging in the wp-config file as well but no luck.

Comment: Do you have a php error_log on your server ? There is maybe an error logged in it

Comment: No, I have no error_log file. As I said I am working on localhost.

Comment: You can have error_log on localhost, do you use something like laragon, wamp, xamp ? they all have php error_log

Answer (score 0):

Install Debug Bar plugin and go to your themes and check what error it log in debug bar.

Comment: Okay I will install the plugin and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

One of your theme file or function is missing, which cause fatal error on your server.
You can check server log by enabling debug mode inside wp-config file after database credentials.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

Then try to access your themes tab again and see errors in wp-content/debug.log file.

**Note:** Disable debug mode on production or you can revoke public access to this file.